# Graph algorithm in C by reading grids into array

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I need to read some objects from console.It is a bit like the battleship game written in C.
Think of it I have a platform of 6x6 array.I am taking the user input from the user and the char 'X' means it is a shaded area in the two dimensional array.I am assigning the chars for the 36 place.The example of the array after user has given the inputs is;

```
0,0                       0,6      

  X              XXX
 X                X  
   XX             X 
     X




6,0                       6,6
```

Sorry the output is not too clear.It is the output of the X chars that user had entered.The 'x' chars in the two groups are unioned and so, there are 2 objects in the graph.I need to count the number of the groups.The direction of the X chars is not able to be symetric, all the thing is there may be group of x chars that are unioned and i want to count the groups

Comment: In both the title and the content of the question he says that it's plain C.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand you/ What is it *exactly* that you are trying to achieve? What did you try? "The number of the groups" are the number of connected sets of x's?

Comment: @amit. yes the number of groups is the connected set of x's. I need to count the connected set of X'S.

Comment: @TheOm3ga But in the tages he said something else. Otherwise, why would I have asked?

Answer (score 1):

Model the problem as the graph (as you already understood): `G=(V,E)`, where `V` is your grid (or only the `x`'s to be more exact), and `E = { (u,v) | there is X in both u and v }`

During parsing, save all your coordinates in an container, and map each to a boolean value indicating if it was visited or not.

Now, repeat while there are still non visited x's:

Run a graph discovery algorithm ([BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) is an example) from this (not visited) `x`, and mark all visited `x`'s encountered during the run of the discovery algorithm

The number of iterations (number of times BFS was invoked) is the number of groups.